# Grails: how to define configuration profile when launching grails war with java command?

Tags: grails

I have a grails 3.0 application packaged as war file, and I would like to run it with java command line. Things looks simple from the reference guide: java -jar my_war_file_name. But I cannot find a way to pass in the profile (dev/test/prod), and also it looks like -D option cannot overwrite the configuration as well. Any idea?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found the problem. I should put -D in front of -jar. So this is working:

java -Dgrails.env=prod -Dserver.port=xxxx -jar my_war_file